# How to get cin multiple times in different lines?

Tags: c++, cin

I want to get input twice with one variable a string and the other character, but it always comes out compilation error, how do I solve this problem. I've tried cin.clear(); but it seems not working in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::getline;

int main(){
    string name;
    cout << "Please input a string." << endl;
    getline (cin, name);
    cout << "Hello, there, "<< name  <<".\n";
    char ccc;
    cout << "Please input a character." << endl;
    getline (cin, ccc);
    cout << "This is a alphabet:" << ccc << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output will be like:

```
Please input a string.
John
Hello, there, John.
Please input a character.
c
This is a alphabet:c
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: [`getline (cin, ccc);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can't be used to input a single character.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `cin.ignore();` before. It should clear the buffer. Also char should use getchar instead of getline.

Answer (score 1):

There is no version of `getline()` which accepts a `char` as its second argument. Instead, you probably want the version which accepts a `char*`. You will need to modify your code to read a string that contains one character.

Answer (score 0):

Try getchar() instead of getline() on the second one.

Comment: Note that `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`, in order to return the special EOF character. Some massaging is required to handle it correctly.